# Just mined with an old version v0.13.0.4 and upgraded to v0.14.0.2. Reward now missing

Tags: mining, monero-forks, block-reward

I am new to this and am experimenting. I am using Debian Sid and apt-get install installed the v013.0.4 version.  After synchronizing, I started to mine using the `monero-wallet-cli` command `start_mining`. After about 4 hours I mined a block.

Probably very very lucky.

I then upgraded to v0.14.0.2 (compiled from source) and then my reward from the previous version mined disappeared. I then restored a backup version of my wallet, but it shows 0 coins after the resync.

Did I lose my coins or never really got them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0.13.0.4 can not understand the current consensus rules, so it's essentially playing in its own abandoned playpen. You never found any Monero. It's a bit similar to participating in a bike race, taking a wrong turn and somehow ending up on last week's bike race's circuit and going over that finish line that's still chalked on the ground. You did not win that race either.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I was expecting something like that, but I wanted confirmation.  I do believe that Debian maintainers (and others) should delete any crypto currency versions prior to any fork.

Comment: Feel free to reach out to the package maintainers (as listed on [this page](https://packages.debian.org/sid/monero)). It is frustrating when people package software for a distribution and then don't maintain it.